# Getting Method threw 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException' exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to hit api1 which gives me a token for authentication for api2. However i'm getting this error from Connection.getOutputStream()   **Method threw 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException' exception**.
Any idea how to fix this?

```
 public HttpsURLConnection getHttpsURLConnection(HttpParameterSetter parameters, URL url, String method) throws IOException {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
        parameters.getHeaders().forEach(connection::setRequestProperty);
        return connection;
    }    


public String requests(URL url) throws Exception {
    url = new URL(url.toString() + "?" + parameters.toString());
    HttpsURLConnection connection = getHttpsURLConnection(this.parameters, url, this.method);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    BufferedReader in = null;
    DataOutputStream wr = null;
    try {
                if (!payload.equals("")) {
                    wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(this.getPayload());
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                }
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                StringBuilder inputLine = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                    inputLine.append(line);
                return inputLine.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception occurred during token call "+e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            } finally {
                try{
                    if (wr != null)
                        wr.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    log.error("Error occurred while closing DataOutputStream in the token call: "+e.getMessage());
                }
                try{
                    if (in != null)
                        in.close();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    log.error("Error occurred while closing BufferedReader in the token call: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
}**strong text**
```

Comment: You need to capture the complete stacktrace for the exception.  The information that explains the problem will be in a nested exception.  (It is likely to be a problem with versions of SSL / TLS, or crypto algorithms, or certificates, or something like that.  But you need the stacktrace to know where to start.)

Answer (score 0):

Does the server you are trying to connect to use a self-signed certificate?
If so, please make sure you have imported the self-signed certificate into your jre KeyStore.

Here is an example:

```
keytool -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -importcert -alias <alias> -file <certificate> -trustcacerts -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

`<certificate>` is the filename of the certificate, such as `xxx.cer` or `xxx.crt`.